# PHP and select in loop

Tags: php, forms, loops

I have a PHP page where its querying data from the database and putting it in a table. The first column is where I would like the user to assign a person to that row. I was able to do that successfully (the select in a loop) but now I'm having a problem when its getting pushed out to the other page.

Below is the first page:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM meetingDump WHERE Meeting_ID IN ($Series)";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs))
{
$ID = odbc_result($rs,"ID");
$Meeting_ID = odbc_result($rs,"Meeting_ID");
$Title = odbc_result($rs,"Title");
$StartTime = odbc_result($rs,"StartTime");
$EndTime = odbc_result($rs,"EndTime");
$Organizer = odbc_result($rs,"Organizer");

echo '<tr>
        <td>';
        {
                $box1 = array();

                $result1 = "SELECT FullName FROM User";
                    $rs1=odbc_exec($connu,$result1);
                while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs1)) { $box1[] = $row; }
                }
                /* Generate select box contents */
                $AssignedTo = '<select name="AssignedTo[]" onchange="autoSubmit()">';
                $AssignedTo .= '<option selected="selected">---< Select Engineer >---</option>';
                if (!empty($box1)) {
                    foreach ($box1 as $k => $v) {
                        $AssignedTo .= '<option value="'.$v['FullName'].'">'.$v['FullName'].'</option>';
                    }
                }
            $AssignedTo .= '</select>';
            /* Output */
            echo $AssignedTo;

        echo '
        </td>
        <input name="AssignedID[]" type="hidden" value="' . $ID . '" />
        <td>' . $Meeting_ID . '</td>
        <td>' . $Title . '</td>
        <td>' . $StartTime . '</td>
        <td>' . $EndTime . '</td>
        <td>' . $Organizer . '</td>';
```

}

Now for the second page I currently have:

```
foreach($_POST['AssignedTo'] as $AssignedTo)
{
echo '<br>' . $AssignedTo;
}
```

That gets me all the selected names, which is perfect, but I'm trying to correlate the assignedTo field with the meeting_id field.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
The comment from  AeroX helped me figure it out!

```
 $AssignedID = $_POST['AssignedID'];
 $AssignedTo = $_POST['AssignedTo'];

 foreach ($AssignedID as $Key => $value)
 {
echo $AssignedID[$Key] .' '. $AssignedTo[$Key];
echo '<br>';
 }
```

Comment: I believe the `$_POST['AssignedTo']` & `$_POST['AssignedID']` should contain a number indexed array. If you get the length of the array and loop  over it where the keys match in both array should be the related id's in this example.

Comment: That did it! If you want to post it as an answer...I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, because of the way the POST variables `$_POST['AssignedID']` and `$_POST['AssignedTo']` will be populated you can just pull the Value from each Array where they both have matching Keys. This will then give you the related records.

Something like the below should work for you:

```
$AssignedID = $_POST['AssignedID'];
$AssignedTo = $_POST['AssignedTo'];

foreach(array_keys($AssignedID) as $Key)
{
    echo $AssignedID[$Key];
    echo $AssignedTo[$Key];
}
```